# Converting the Python file (from the Kivi library used in it) to an executable file

Tags: kivy, pyinstaller, exe

I have made a game using Kivi library. When I want to get output from it for Windows, I encounter many problems.

I tried using auto py to exe and pyinstaller. When the Kivi library is installed and I want to get an output, it starts executing vague and endless commands and never creates the output. When I remove the Kivi library and try again, it generates the output for me, but when I run it, it cannot find the Kiwi library and I get an error.

Comment: Share your pyinstaller spec file.  Issues with pyinstaller usually have to do with paths.